# How to evaluate this using algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

We have $$1.001^6 - 1.001^5$$

How do I evaluate this? Normally I would use algebra to rewrite it, but I don't know how to cleverly rewrite $a^6 - a^5$ to a simpler form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about (let $x = 0.001$ for simpler writing)
\begin{align*}
  (1+x)^6 - (1+x)^5 &= (1+x)^5 \cdot (1+x - 1)\\
      &= x \cdot (1+x)^5\\
      &= x^6 + 5x^5 + 10x^4 + 10x^3 + 5x^2 + x\\
      &= 0.001\,005\,010\,010\,005\,001
\end{align*}